# How can I use WhatsApp Web on Ubuntu?

Tags: whatsapp

I tried to install WhatsApp Web on Ubuntu. I have a Nexus 5 where my WhatsApp works fine. I tried to install the software to my Ubuntu but it asks QR code. I took a picture of it by my phone. But I don't know how to tell the WhatsApp web that I already took the picture. Can anyone help?

Comment: Make sure you are taking the picture of the QR code with your Whatsapp app in your phone and not with the camera app. It will then automatically connect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need for an installation. Just surf to [whatsapp web](https://web.whatsapp.com/):

```
https://web.whatsapp.com/
```

You get an QR-code presented. Start the whatsapp-app on you mobile and select "whatsapp web" from the app-menu. Than you can scan the QR-code from the screen of your webbrowser.

The mobile and the PC should be in same network, the mobile by WLAN.

Comment: well that's the best!!!